Flutter RenderBox was not laid out SingleChildScrollView
My code:
var _body = Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
      top: 340),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      _customWidget,
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                CustomWidget(
                  txt: 'item1',
                  txt2: 'info',
                  callback: () {
                    _showDialog(context);
                  },
                ),
                CustomWidget(
                  txt: 'item1',
                  txt2: 'info',
                  callback: () {
                    _showDialog(context);
                  },
                  },
                ),
                CustomWidget(
                  txt: 'item1',
                  txt2: 'info',
                  callback: () {
                    _showDialog(context);
                  },
                ),
                _customWidget,
                _customWidget,
              ],
            )),
      )
    ],
  ),
);

Another exception was thrown: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.
Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#97324 relayoutBoundary=up40 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I have tried wrapping children into expanded and that does not work.
I cannot add any height to my scrollview because the children inside scrollview will only show if a condition is correct. So the height of the list depends on how many children that will show.
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
                    backgroundColor: AppColors.mainColor,
                    body: Container(
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          _body,
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
}

Class:
    class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String txt;
  final String? txt2;
  final GestureTapCallback? callback;

  SettingsItemWidget({
    required this.txt,
    this.txt2,
    this.callback,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        if (callback != null) {
          callback!();
        }
      },
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, left: 30.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        txt,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontFamily: "Sofia",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: const                       EdgeInsets.only(right:20.0),10.0),
                      child: Text(
                        txt2 ?? '',
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.grey[400],
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          fontFamily: "Sofia",
                        ),
                      )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 0.1,
            color: Colors.white70,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


can you share a running code on dartpad.dev that will reproduce this error

What do you need for that?

your widget tree including CustomWidget are hidden and to reproduce the error . More about minimal-reproducible-example

Can you try it now?

Can you provide a full code in one block? I am tired of rewriting your code on my end.

Just copy the 3 code blocks

I think you want to make a SingleChildScrollView with a limited height.
You can wrap it with a Container or SizedBox and specify the height you want.
For example like this:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const TstApp());
}

class TstApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TstApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Tst',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  HomePage({super.key});
  final Widget _customWidget = CustomWidget(
    txt: 'txt',
    txt2: 'txt2',
    callBack: () {},
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10), // was: 340
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            _customWidget,
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            SizedBox(
              height: 300,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    CustomWidget(
                      txt: 'item1',
                      txt2: 'info',
                      callBack: () {
                        _showDialog(context);
                      },
                    ),
                    CustomWidget(
                      txt: 'item2',
                      txt2: 'info',
                      callBack: () {
                        _showDialog(context);
                      },
                    ),
                    CustomWidget(
                      txt: 'item3',
                      txt2: 'info',
                      callBack: () {
                        _showDialog(context);
                      },
                    ),
                    _customWidget,
                    _customWidget,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Alert'),
          content: const Text('This is a simple alert dialog.'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: const Text('OK'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.txt,
    required this.txt2,
    this.callBack,
  });
  final String txt;
  final String txt2;
  final VoidCallback? callBack;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(txt),
      subtitle: Text(txt2),
      onTap: callBack,
    );
  }
}


I don't want a limited height since I have my custom widgets to show and it will be different amount depending on some states but thanks

I did try this but I still get the same error
